# Liquidsoap -- reading metadata

Tags: internet-radio, liquidsoap

I'm running a basic liquidsoap server with a playlist like:
myplaylist = playlist(mode="normal", "liquidlist.m3u",reload_mode="watch")

I've found that if I include metadata in the .m3u playlist in the "EXT" extended format, the metadata is loaded correctly. However, I would like to load the metadata from the files in the playlist rather than from the playlist file itself.

When I do not specify the metadata in the playlist, the fields are blank, however, this may be because it's still looking for metadata in the playlist.

Is there a way to specify that the metadata is loaded from the files, rather than from the playlist?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why this happened/how to fix it, but I was able to workaround the issue by updating to Liquidsoap 1.3.6.